# Loop through array indexes that have the same key? (JavaScript/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, key

I've been trying to run through the first index while checking *only* each index's `id`, not its name. I'm not trying to get every key->value within each element. Simply put, I only want to know each element's `id` value. If it matches the condition inside the loop, I want to display only its name.

My problem is that it will grab the value of the index `i`, but not the value of `id`.

```
var offices = [
    {id: 1, name: "Miami"},
    {id: 2, name: "San Francisco"}
];


for (i = 0; i < offices.length; i++) {

    if (offices[i]['id'] === 1){
        $('#edit_office').val(offices[i]['name']);
        //#edit_office is an input[type="text"]
    }

}
```

How would I do this?

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Your loop works fine as-is.

Comment: Umm... what's the issue?  Your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/NvZWS/

Comment: Verified, it works sir! http://jsfiddle.net/r7y3y/ Also, I recommend checking out Underscore.js (http://underscorejs.org/) if you are doing a lot of object manipulation.

Comment: As other pointed out your code seems fine.  Although I personally prefer the dot syntax for accessing properties `offices[i].id`